# Faster method of reading screen pixel in Python than PIL?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, directx, python-imaging-library

Currently I'm using a pixel reader via AutoItv3 to perform some actions in a program that is running direct X; A game.  Right now the program works fine but as an exercise I've been rewriting it in python.  Right now I can do:

```
import ImageGrab  # Part of PIL
    image = ImageGrab.grab() #Define an area to capture.
    rgb = image.getpixel((1, 90)) #What pixel do we want?
```

And that grabs the pixel info I want just fine, but I'm doing this quite rapidly (needs to be done 3x a second or faster), but the result is that it majorly affects the framerate of this DirectX-based game.

Is there a faster way in Python to read a specific screen pixel?  Even limiting this one to running every 0.3 seconds is causing more strain than it really should (I actually figured python would be *faster* than AutoIt for this particular purpose, hence the reason I'm trying it)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the PIL's grabscreen source, Its does not accept any parameters, and Its grab the whole screen and convert it to bitmap.

```
PyImaging_GrabScreenWin32(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int width, height;
    HBITMAP bitmap;
    BITMAPCOREHEADER core;
    HDC screen, screen_copy;
    PyObject* buffer;

    /* step 1: create a memory DC large enough to hold the
       entire screen */

    screen = CreateDC(";DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL); 
    screen_copy = CreateCompatibleDC(screen); 

    width = GetDeviceCaps(screen, HORZRES);
    height = GetDeviceCaps(screen, VERTRES);

    bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screen, width, height);
    if (!bitmap)
        goto error;

    if (!SelectObject(screen_copy, bitmap))
        goto error;

    /* step 2: copy bits into memory DC bitmap */

    if (!BitBlt(screen_copy, 0, 0, width, height, screen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
        goto error;

    /* step 3: extract bits from bitmap */

    buffer = PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, height * ((width*3 + 3) & -4));
    if (!buffer)
        return NULL;

    core.bcSize = sizeof(core);
    core.bcWidth = width;
    core.bcHeight = height;
    core.bcPlanes = 1;
    core.bcBitCount = 24;
    if (!GetDIBits(screen_copy, bitmap, 0, height, PyString_AS_STRING(buffer),
                   (BITMAPINFO*) &core, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        goto error;

    DeleteObject(bitmap);
    DeleteDC(screen_copy);
    DeleteDC(screen);

    return Py_BuildValue("(ii)N", width, height, buffer);

error:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, "screen grab failed");

    DeleteDC(screen_copy);
    DeleteDC(screen);

    return NULL;
}
```

So, when I just go a little deep, found C approach is good

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909(VS.85).aspx

And Python has ctypes, so here is my approach using ctypes (in Windows 10, `winnt` has been replaced with `Windows`):

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> user= windll.LoadLibrary("c:\\winnt\\system32\\user32.dll") #I am in windows 2000, may be yours will be windows
>>> h = user.GetDC(0)
>>> gdi= windll.LoadLibrary("c:\\winnt\\system32\\gdi32.dll")
>>> gdi.GetPixel(h,1023,767)
16777215 #I believe its white color of RGB or BGR value, #FFFFFF (according to msdn it should be RGB)
>>> gdi.GetPixel(h,1024,767)
-1 #because my screen is only 1024x768
```

You could write a wrapper for function GetPixel like this

```
from ctypes import windll
dc= windll.user32.GetDC(0)

def getpixel(x,y):
    return windll.gdi32.GetPixel(dc,x,y)
```

Then you can use like `getpixel(0,0)`, `getpixel(100,0)`, etc...

<s>PS: Mine is Windows 2000, so I put `winnt` in the path, you may need to change it to `windows` or you chould completely remove path, just using `user32.dll` and `gdi32.dll` should work too.</s>

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  This sped up screen reading NOTICEABLY.  I can read as fast as I want now with virtually no slowdown. ;)

Comment: I tried the above syntax for ctypes and couldn't get it working with LoadLibrary.  The wrapper function code is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I can't believe this actually works with time at least 30 times for second. I've tried GetPixel and it took enormouse amount of time.

Comment: See [my addition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623486/12291742) to this answer.

Answer (score 7):

Comment on S.Mark's solution: user32 library is already loaded by windll into windll.user32, so instead of the dc = ... line you can do:

```
def getpixel(x,y):
    return gdi.GetPixel(windll.user32.GetDC(0),x,y)
```

...or preferably:

```
dc= windll.user32.GetDC(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with `cdll.user32.GetDC(0)` this morning, it was not working, so I importing dll files manually.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it via SDL (?). Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934151/direct-screen-pixel-framebuffer-access), SDL can access the screen. And it has python bindings.

Might be worth a shot? If it worked it would certainly be faster than doing a full screen capture in PIL.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but it ranks quite highly on Google when searching for Python screen grab methods, so I think it might be useful to mention that the ImageGrab module now supports grabbing a region of the screen:

```
PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)
Parameters: bbox – What region to copy. Default is the entire screen.
Returns:    An image
```

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html

Expanding the scope slightly, there is now also a replacement for ImageGrab called pyscreenshot, that also saves some part of the screen to a or PIL/Pillow image. This module also works on Linux, unlike ImageGrab which is Windows and OS X only.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,510,510)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
im.show()
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to answer of @YOU, this function returns the RGB value of a given pixel as a tuple. I compared the outputs with `PIL.ImageGrab` and this works fine:

```py
from ctypes import windll
dc= windll.user32.GetDC(0)

def getpixel(x,y):
    return tuple(int.to_bytes(windll.gdi32.GetPixel(dc,x,y), 3, "little"))
```

Note that this code does not have error handling.