# Get color at point of mouse click in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I'm  working on a program (in Linux) where I need to know the color at the point where of mouse click. I can't install external modules (PIL is fine though). I did try and see if there are solutions posted in the net ([Return RGB Color of Image Pixel under Mouse Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647120/return-rgb-color-of-image-pixel-under-mouse-tkinter)) but all of them seem to use modules which I'll have to install. Is there a way I can do it with these restrictions in mind?

Comment: If `PIL` is the `Pillow` module, then it has sub-module to get the color of a pixel on screen.

Comment: Yes, but if I'm not wrong, you need to specify an image file for that. I want to fetch the colour at a point on the Tkinter window...

Comment: @RichieHarvy even if it is only possible to do that with an image (maybe it doesn't require one, but...), PIL also provides screenshoting ability which means you can screenshot the screen and get the location of the mouse pointer's position and then get the color from the image with that

Comment: See [`ImageGrab`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html#PIL.ImageGrab.grab) module and [`.winfo_pointerxy()`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M26).

Comment: you can use module `io` to use PIL with image in memory instead of reading from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short script that enables colors to be found and displayed in `tkinter`.

It uses `PIL ImageGrab.grab()` to grab the entire screen as `pic` then you simply press space-bar to find the color under the mouse pointer. It uses `pic.getpixel(x, y)`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab

master = tk.Tk()
master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
master.title("Colors")

button = tk.Button(master, text = "Press Spacebar")
button.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width = 200, height = 200)
canvas.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

pic = ImageGrab.grab()

def color():
    x, y = master.winfo_pointerx(), master.winfo_pointery()
    r, g, b = pic.getpixel((x, y))
    hue = f"#{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}"
    button.config( text = f"{x}, {y} =  {hue}")
    canvas["background"] = hue

button["command"] = color
button.focus_force()

master.mainloop()
```