# Python Screen Capture for Ambilight (less resource intensive)

Tags: python, windows, winapi, screen, capture

I'm just developing a little script for screen capturing with Python and analyzing the data for Ambilight. It's already working, but I have some performance issues:

- my script takes about 25%-50% CPU resources while watching youtube (current i5-2410M @ fullHD, script should be optimized for i7-6670k @ 4k (my new pc))
- I'm able to capture about 11 fps, which is enough for ambilight, but if I would be able to capture faster, I can put delays between the shots and reduce resources
- Only the main monitor is captured, would be great if I can choose.

My Script:

```
import time
import asyncio
import websockets
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageStat
from PIL import ImageEnhance

# Analyzing the image and deleting black borders from movies (21:9 or 4:3)
def analyze_borders(debug=False):
    min_size = 3
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    width, height = im.size
    box = []
    for x in range(0, height):
        # check top
        line = im.crop((0, x, width, x + 1))
        if debug:
            print("TOP", ImageStat.Stat(line).median)
        if ImageStat.Stat(line).median > [1, 1, 1]:
            box.append(x)
            break
        if x >= height / min_size:
            box.append(int(height / min_size))
            break
    for x in range(height, 0, -1):
        # check bottom
        line = im.crop((0, x, width, x + 1))
        if debug:
            print("BOTTOM", ImageStat.Stat(line).median)
        if ImageStat.Stat(line).median > [1, 1, 1]:
            box.append(height - x - 1)
            break
        if x <= height / min_size:
            box.append(int(height / min_size))
            break
    for x in range(0, width):
        # check left
        line = im.crop((x, 0, x + 1, height))
        if debug:
            print("LEFT", ImageStat.Stat(line).median)
        if ImageStat.Stat(line).median > [1, 1, 1]:
            box.append(x)
            break
        if x >= width / min_size:
            box.append(int(width / min_size))
            break
    for x in range(width, 0, -1):
        # check right
        line = im.crop((x, 0, x + 1, height))
        if debug:
            print("RIGHT", ImageStat.Stat(line).median)
        if ImageStat.Stat(line).median > [1, 1, 1]:
            box.append(width - x - 1)
            break
        if x <= width / min_size:
            box.append(int(width / min_size))
            break
    return box


def capture():
    return ImageGrab.grab()


@asyncio.coroutine
def start():
    time1 = time.time()
    websocket = yield from websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8887/')
    for x in range(0, 1000):
        im = capture()
        im = ImageEnhance.Color(im).enhance(1)
        im = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im).enhance(1)
        box = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        if x % 100 == 0:
            box = analyze_borders()
            print(box)
        w, h = im.size
        im = im.crop((box[2], box[0], w - box[3], h - box[1]))
        w, h = im.size
        im1 = im.crop((0, 0, int(w / 2), h))
        im2 = im.crop((int(w / 2), 0, w, h))
        stat1 = ImageStat.Stat(im1)
        stat2 = ImageStat.Stat(im2)
        # print(str(x) + " Median1: " + str(stat1.median))
        # print(str(x) + " Median2: " + str(stat2.median))
        yield from websocket.send(str("C1:(" + str(stat1.median[0]) +
                                      ", " + str(stat1.median[1]) +
                                      ", " + str(stat1.median[2]) + ")"))
        yield from websocket.send(str("C2:(" + str(stat2.median[0]) +
                                      ", " + str(stat2.median[1]) +
                                      ", " + str(stat2.median[2]) + ")"))
    yield from websocket.close()
    duration = time.time() - time1
    print(str(duration))
    print(str(1000 / duration))


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
```

The Websocket part is because my LED Stripes are connected to a RaspberryPi which receives the messages. There might be some performance optimization but I think the main problem is in PIL.

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23155761/5481935

I think this is the best method but I don't understand how I can capture the whole screen with win32ui and crop it into parts because I'm just starting with python. At the moment I just crop two parts, but as soon as I have my digital LED Stripe installed behind my screen I am going to capture bit more parts.

Thank you from Germany,
Johannes

Edit: I think most optimization is possible at the capture method. Also I think the answer I linked above is very good, but I don't understand how to connect the answer from above with my code: So how can I capture the whole Screen with win32ui and process the result like in my code or convert it to a PIL image?

Comment: Since you don't need full resolution you might be able to use the [DWM Thumbnails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541.aspx) for your purposes. This is a lot more lightweight, since a) they are already there, and b) you don't need to transfer the entire window's bitmap.

Comment: @IInspectable but I want to capture the whole screen and not just one window

Answer (score 0):

PIL already implements an `analyze_borders` like function: [getbbox](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.getbbox). Use this instead for better performance, because iterating over the rows & columns of a image in Python will be slow.

You might also want to convert the PIL image into a `numpy` 2D array. `numpy` arrays can be easily analyzed in a variety of ways. For instance, to compute the median pixel value across all rows, you would simply do `numpy.median(img, axis=1)`.

Comment: getbbox() is great! But I tried numpy and it's only half as fast as PIL.

Comment: That's expected. -- `getbbox()` is implemented in the extension module (C API) & doesn't have to compute the median for every row. I was suggesting `numpy` arrays in case you wanted to do fancy image analysis.